# Set default browser for Electron applications

Tags: google-chrome, electron, slack

Is there a way to define (environment variables, configuration) a default browser for Electron apps? I am trying to ensure that Slack will always open links in Slack with a specific browser / Chrome profile.

Is this configurable or does it ultimately default to OS default browser settings with no way to intercept?

Comment: Are you asking for how to configure your OS so that links from within Electron apps will open only a specific browser? That'll be vastly different depending on the OS you're on (and is, AFAIK, impossible on Linux). Electron will call out to the OS to ask how to handle a link.